# Php check string for correct format before insert into the database

Tags: php, mysql, regex

Looking for some help on how to validate a string in PHP.

My string contains:

```
4 NUMBER
1 DOT
4 NUMBER
1 CHARACTER
```

all in one entry, so like `1103.5696N`

I need to make sure/validate this before inserting in the DB.

Can one of the wizard help me out there?

Comment: And what you have tried so far

Comment: i don't no how to do?Can u suggest me some ideas..

Comment: And the thing that you really need over here is **REGEX** Do some research and post that values over here with your attempts

Comment: @RaviSrk any questions or issues with answer posted?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a starting point, https://regex101.com/r/eI8iK4/1.

Usage in PHP:

```
$input = '1103.5696N';
if(preg_match('~^\d{4}\.\d{4}.$~', $input)) {
    echo 'Valid';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid';
}
```

I think you may want less than 4 numbers though for the beginning and ending values. This also seems like lat/long coordinates so maybe instead of any character at the end you only want `N`, `S`, `E`, or `W`? I will leave that to you to resolve though.